# GitLab contact IdP with GET instead of POST with SAML

Tags: ruby, gitlab, saml

I have a little problem with SAML configuration with Gitlab.

After the exchange of metadatas with my IdP I try the SSO connection but it fails.
The IdP team analyzed my AuthnRequest and it was correct but thez said it was sent using a GET instead of the expected POST.

Here is my SAML config in Gitlab

```ruby
gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = ['saml']
gitlab_rails['omniauth_block_auto_created_users'] = false
gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_link_ldap_user'] = false
gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_link_saml_user'] = true

gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] =
[
{
name: "saml",
args:
{
assertion_consumer_service_url: "https://my.website/gitlab/auth/saml/callback",
assertion_consumer_service_binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
idp_cert:"
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIFZ.... -----END CERTIFICATE-----
",

idp_sso_target_url: "https://my_idp_target_URL",
idp_sso_target_binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
sso_binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
protocol_binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
issuer: "sp-gitlab",
name_identifier_format: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent',


certificate: "
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIFZ.... -----END CERTIFICATE-----
",
private_key:"
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEFZ... -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
",
security: {
authn_requests_signed: true,
embed_sign: true,
digest_method: "XMLSecurity::Document::SHA1",
signature_method: "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"
}
},
label: "SSO"
}
]
```

I thought the parameter "sso_binding" defines the method used to send the AuthnRequest but I can get wrong...

What am I missing ? 
Is there a particular way to define the method used ?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is late, I found a solution for this:

as documented here: https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml#the-initialization-phase

and tested here: https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml/blob/2b2170d9e7c368209d0d61c318e29f30733c8e8a/test/request_test.rb#L245

you have to use: `idp_sso_target_binding: ':post'`

This worked for my latest gitlab installation with omnibus.

All the best!